# Share connection between Bookshelfjs queries

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js

Let's suppose I have these two models below:

```
var user = Bookshelf.Model.extend({ tableName: 'users' });
var configuration = Bookshelf.Model.extend({ tableName: 'configurations' });

user.fetchAll().then(function(users) {
    configuration.fetchAll().then(function(configurations) {
        // Do something...
    });
});
```

Do anyone knows if the `fetchAll()` calls shares the opened connection? Or maybe every database call uses a specific connection? If they don't share, is there a way to specify to use the same connection until I close the operation or something? How BookshelfJS behaves in this matter?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Bookshelf.js uses Knex.js under the hoods so the answer to your question lies in how Knex handles connections.

Knex can use connection pooling from the [generic-pool-redux](https://github.com/bookshelf/generic-pool-redux) library. It has a default of 2 open connection and a maximum of 10 for postgres and mysql databases and a single connection for sqlite.

This is an example of configuration file to change the default values.

```
development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
        database: 'db',
        user:     'username',
        password: 'mypassword',
        charset : 'utf8'
    },
    pool: {
        min: 5,
        max: 20
    },
    migrations: {
        tableName: 'migrations'
    }
}
```

And his is a portion of the bookshelf documentation for fetchAll

> Fetches a collection of models from the database, using any query parameters currently set on the model to form a select query

So it will form a single Knex query and execute it consuming only one connection.

Depending on your configuration file it will use a single connection for everything or any available from the pool.

There is an [option](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-connection) that allow you to change the connection used to execute the query but for that you must invoke the bookshelf [query()](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-query) method to tap directly into the Knex query builder.